# SQL query that groups by one hour intervals starting from the current minute?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a table that has a `Created` column and a `Code` column. And data is being inserted into it every 1 minute with a recurring job, so it shouldn't have any date gaps.

I want to group it to 1 hour intervals, for the last 24 hours, starting from the current minute (when the query was executed - so I would get that minute with `GETUTCDATE()`) and then calculate the `Percentage` column for that group using a simple `AVG(Percentage)`.

So far I've only managed to round down to the nearest hour, and my result set looks like this:

```
2023-03-01 15:00:00
2023-03-01 16:00:00
2023-03-01 17:00:00
```

This is achieved using this part of the query:

```
GROUP BY 
Code,
DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, Created), 0)
```

However, what I want to achieve is, if the current date is for example `2023-03-01 15:27:48`, then I want the result set to be grouped from the minute, with 1 hour intervals. So it should look like this:

```
2023-03-01 15:27:00
2023-03-01 14:27:00
2023-03-01 13:27:00
2023-03-01 12:27:00
```

Comment: Just use DATEPART to get the current minute and then DATEADD to append the minutes.

Comment: If you were on 2022, then you could consider `DATE_BUCKET` (unfortunately, you're on 2016).

Comment: how about change `hour` to `minute` in the two places of your code?

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis that would return a fairly large result set and defeats the purpose of grouping I think, because a new row is inserted every minute anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```sql
select DATEADD(hour, datediff(hour, Created, GETDATE()), GETDATE())
, datediff(hour, Created, GETDATE())
, count(*)
from yourtable so
group by datediff(hour, Created, GETDATE())
```

EDIT for minute-wise variant:

```sql
select  DATEADD(hour, datediff(hour, Created, currDate), currDate)
,   datediff(hour, Created, currDate), count(*)
from yourtable so
cross apply (
    select dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, getdate()), 0) AS currDate
    ) cd
group by datediff(hour, Created, currDate),currDate
```

Comment: This appears to have fixed my problem, thanks!